# Can I import files from outside /app in Ember CLI?

Tags: ember-cli

In my addon I import a file from the host app's `/app/mirage` folder ([source](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/blob/abde9509bbdd277d1e76fd15859e3a4735212a14/app/initializers/ember-cli-mirage.js#L2)):

```
import userConfig from '../mirage/config';
```

I want to move the `/mirage` folder to the root of the project, i.e. not put it under `/app`. When I tried this,

```
import userConfig from '../../mirage/config';
```

it wasn't found, I assume because the mirage tree wasn't getting merged during the build.

How can I include it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's outside of the app tree, the easiest way is including the app's name (as defined in your `package.json`) in the import:

```
import userConfig from 'app-name/mirage/config'
```

Needing to know the app's name might be troublesome in an addon though.
The 'proper' Ember-CLI way would be turning your dependecy into a seperate addon or a bower package. Have a look [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies/) for further reading. This way your addon would need this depedency to be installed in the main app.